# Regex to match Postgres "operator name" rules

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying (and failing) to write a **JavaScript** regular expression to match a PostgreSQL ***operator name***, [defined in the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-OPERATORS) as:

> An operator name is a sequence of up to `NAMEDATALEN`-1 (63 by default) characters from the following list:
>
> ```
> + - * / < > = ~ ! @ # % ^ & | ` ?
> ```
>
> There are a few restrictions on operator names, however:
>
> - -- and /* cannot appear anywhere in an operator name, since they will be taken as the start of a comment.
> - A multiple-character operator name cannot end in + or -, unless the name also contains at least one of these characters:
>
>   ```
>   ! @ # % ^ & | ` ?
>   ```
>
>   For example, @- is an allowed operator name, but *- is not. This restriction allows PostgreSQL to parse SQL-compliant queries without requiring spaces between tokens.

Other than the Regex-noob:

```
[\+\-\*\/\<\>\=\~\!\@\#\%\^\&\|\`\?]+
```

I'm failing hard to get any further, especially the *"`--` and `/*` can't appear in the matched string"* requirements. I've tried wrestling [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) into it, but with no success.

Is this even possible all in a single Regex? (it's to work within the https://github.com/no-context/moo so no opportunity fallback to regular JS).

**Any pointers very gratefully received!**

I've tried things like `(?!.*\-\-)[\+\-\*\/\<\>\=\~\!\@\#\%\^\&\|\`?]+`, but to no avail.

Comment: Is it a requirement that it’s a regex? Pulling language artifacts out of a blob of language is generally easier with a parser.

Comment: @DaveNewton Unfortunately yes, regex is a requirement as it's to yield a token as part of a Moo-based lexer.

Comment: @cyberbrain: Apologies, an operator can be up-to 63 characters long (I omitted that from the quote, maybe that's to blame for the confusion?), so the strings `--` and `/*` can't feature anywhere in the matched string, even though the individual characters of `-`, `/` and `*` can.

Comment: @Bergi : I updated the question to contain the correct quote and also the link to the source. Now it makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex will capture operator names from a multi-line string.

```
/(?:^|[\t ])(?!\S*?(?:--|\/\*))(?![+\-*\/<>=]+[+\-](?=[\s,]))([+\-*\/<>=~!@#%\^&|`?]{1,63})/gm
```

Breakdown:

```
(?:^|[\t ])           <- Operator name is at start of line or is preceded by whitespace.
(?!\S*?(?:--|\/\*))   <- It may not contain "--" or "/*"
                         The `\S` is so we stop if we hit a space.
(?![+\-*\/<>=]+[+\-](?=[\s,]))  
                      <- May not end in "+" or "-" if missing certain characters.
                         Determine end of operator by looking for whitespace or comma.
                         Class has all allowed chars minus ones that MUST be present.
([+\-*\/<>=~!@#%\^&|`?]{1,63})
                      <- Contains a sequence of 1 to 63 of a set of allowed characters.
```

Tested against the following data:

```
[GOOD]
-
+ +
* *<
/ < > >*
= ~ !
@ # % ^
& | < >
*->

[BAD]
--
/*
+--
@/*
*-
<+
++
*-,

[MIX]
!!@ #/*
#/* !!@
NEGATOR = !==,
!==,*-, #-
```

One of the challenges of defining the boundaries of these operators to determine the last character is that you can't use the word boundary symbol, `\b`, which looks for the transition between word and non-word characters, as our operators are made from non-word characters.

Comment: Thank you for this. I noticed the otherwise brilliant answer by Bergi didn't match `@-`
 and yours did (which was noted in the docs as being valid).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in a character class none of these except `-` (and `^`, if it were at the beginning) need to be backslash-escaped, so you can simplify to

```
/[+\-*\/<>=~!@#%^&|`?]+/
```

To avoid matching comments, the easiest solution is lookahead:

```
/(?:(?!--|\/\*)[+\-*\/<>=~!@#%^&|`?])+/
```

but you can also spell it out to something like "*`-` followed by a valid character except `-`, or `/` followed by a valid character except `-`, or valid character except `-` or `/`*", but that gets complicated quickly with repetition still not forming forbidden patterns.

For "*cannot end in `+` or `-`, unless it also contains at least one […]*", you can also use lookaround:

```
/(?=.*[~!@#%^&|`?]|.*[^+-]$)(?:(?!--|\/\*)[+\-*\/<>=~!@#%^&|`?])+/
```

But given you want to use this for a lexer, the `$` anchor probably does not work so you'll need to use

```
/(?:(?!--|\/\*)[+\-*\/<>=~!@#%^&|`?])+(?<![+-])|[+-]|(?:(?!--|\/\*)[+\-*\/<>=~!@#%^&|`?])*[~!@#%^&|`?](?:(?!--|\/\*)[+\-*\/<>=~!@#%^&|`?])*/
```

Comment: OMG this is brilliant! Thank you so much. Looking at the Postgres docs again, I don't think what they've written is quite as specific as it needs-to-be? Even though all their rules are all obeyed... your second regex appears to exclude single character operator names (e.g. just `+`, `-`, `*` etc. ?), which I think need to match?  Is there a way to adjust the regex to support those please? Thanks again.

Comment: Oh right, just add `|[+-]`. I missed that the restriction is only for multiple-character names.

Comment: That is exquisite... thank you so much Bergi!